# Kotlin unit test assertEquals not working

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am trying to code a unit test in Android Studio.

In debug mode, when I reach the breakpoint I have the following variable :

```
token!!.length = 392
```

And the following assertion is never ok :

```
assertEquals(392, token!!.length)
```

I don't understand how that can be.

And the Run output is :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :392
Actual   :0
 <Click to see difference>

    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.activity.screen.myapp.ExampleUnitTest.get_auth_token_isCorrect(ExampleUnitTest.kt:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

janv. 16, 2019 2:29:40 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFOS: --> POST https://theauthwebsite/api/auth/token http/1.1

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Source code :

```
    var token: String? = "" 

    var user = user("support@mycompany.fr","aaaabbbb", "1") 

    AuthService.getAuthToken(user).enqueue(object : Callback<Result> { 

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Result>, response: Response<Result>) { 
            if (response.isSuccessful) { 
                token = response.body()!!.result!!.token 
            } 
        } 

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Result>, t: Throwable) { 
            token = ""; 
        } 
    }) 

    assertEquals(392, token!!.length)  // Here token really has a length of 392 so that it should be ok but it is not
}
```

EDIT : The solution is to use a synchronous request so the code was modified by the following one :

```
token = authServices.getAuthToken(user).execute().body()!!.result!!.token

assertEquals(392, token!!.length)
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: The logical conclusion would be that the token variable isn't actually 392 characters long. Have you checked the actual length of the token?
EDIT: Your stacktrace shows that your token has a length of 0. So obviously the assert fails.

Comment: Is it coming from API?

Comment: Yes in debug mode, I set a breakpoint just before the assertion, and I right click on the variable token and click on "Evaluate expression" and in the Evaluate window I enter "token!!.length" and the result is "392".

Comment: Yes it is coming from API (Retrofit)

Comment: Is some other function modifying the value of the token variable?

Comment: No other function modifies the value of the token variable. And I have well set a breakpoint just before the assertEquals test and the token length is 392. So the assertion should be ok. But it is not.

Comment: Are you trying to set the length of the token value directly with `token!!.length = 392`?

Comment: No, the token is retrieved from a remote RESTful API method. And then it has a length of 392. and the variable is not modified in any mean.

Comment: I don't think there is enough to go on with the code you have posted here. Can you post the code where `token` is initialized and/or set?

Comment: @KotlinIsland Please update your question with the code you just posted.

Comment: Ok I have added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asserting too early. The asynchronous token request has not completed yet when the test reaches the assert.

`enqueue()` smells like Retrofit. Use `execute()` instead to make the call synchronous.

Comment: Thanks ! That's it !

Comment: I have moved the assertion in the onResponse function but now the problem is inversed : the assertion is always true... I'll try to change to a synchronous call...

Answer (score 3):

You are not waiting for the result. The `enqueue()` method executes the request asynchronously. This means that the callback will not occur on the same thread. After you've made the `enqueue()` call, the assert will immediately be called next. At this point, neither callback will have been called yet so the value of `token` hasn't changed yet. If you want to synchronously wait for the result, use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()`.

Comment: No it is not failing. I have set a breakpoint on the assertEquals test and in the Evaluate window when I enter "token!!.length" the result is 392 and the token variable contains a string of length 392.

Comment: You are correct, I just realised the actual problem. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Do you have the solution ? :)

Comment: I have moved the assertion in the onResponse function and it is now ok ! Thanks again !!!!

Comment: I have moved the assertion in the onResponse function but the assertion is now always true, even with bad authentication credentials. I'll try a synchronous call as suggested by laalto.

Comment: That's happening because the test finishes before the asynchronous callback is called. For testing purposes, a synchronous callback will serve you better.